# Rust sha1::Sha1 result is different from shasum

Tags: rust, hash, sha1

I'm computing the SHA1 digest in Rust via `sha1` crate and use the values as a part of a larger utility.

```rust
use sha1::{Digest, Sha1};

fn main() {
    for s in vec![
        "a",
        "string",
        "some text",
        "https://example.com",
    ] {
        compute_digest(s);
    }
}

fn compute_digest(s: &str) {
    let mut hasher = Sha1::new();
    hasher.update(s);
    let digest = hasher.finalize();
    println!("{s:20} -> {digest:x}");
}
```

The output:

```
a                    -> 86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8
string               -> ecb252044b5ea0f679ee78ec1a12904739e2904d
some text            -> 37aa63c77398d954473262e1a0057c1e632eda77
https://example.com  -> 327c3fda87ce286848a574982ddd0b7c7487f816
```

I created a test where I compare the actually computed keys with expected values. The expected values computed using `shasum` utility (macOS) as follows. But the output is different from the crate's results.

```bash
echo "a" | shasum -a 1
# 3f786850e387550fdab836ed7e6dc881de23001b

echo "string" | shasum -a 1
# edbf08a562d55ca08be8d118430892695f28d432

echo "some text" | shasum -a 1
# a5c341bec5c89ed16758435069e3124b3685ad93

echo "https://example.com" | shasum -a 1
# 104f444c99548d6fcc870aeddf94096b790ff56e
```

Why is that? I guess there is some difference in the functionality of the default `Sha1::new()` instance and `shasum`, but I cannot grasp what it is.

Comment: `echo -n` is, unfortunately, not portable, and on some systems prints literally `-n`.  `printf` is better and its behaviour is standardized.

Comment: fair enough, your answer confirmed my newline suspicions anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `echo` always appends a newline to the output.  Thus, the output you're getting for `echo "a"` contains the two bytes 0x61 and 0x0a, whereas your hash of `a` in Rust is only computing the byte 0x61.

If you want to verify these at the command line, use `printf` instead.  Note that the first argument contains a format string (just like for `printf(3)`), so if you want to include a percent sign, you either need to double it or write `printf '%s' "$ARGUMENT"`.

So doing that makes this work properly:

```
$ printf 'a' | shasum -a 1
86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8  -
$ printf 'a\n' | shasum -a 1
3f786850e387550fdab836ed7e6dc881de23001b  -
```

Note, however, that SHA-1 is insecure and should not be used in any new software.  If you need a cryptographic hash function, use SHA-256 (or any of the SHA-2, SHA-3, or BLAKE2 hashes) instead.

Comment: Ah, it is not the first time echo's newline character bites me, but I've completely forgotten that nuance, again! Thank you! I should rather use `printf` next time whenever I need to have an exact string representation... (P.S.: yes, you're totally right regarding cryptographic applications; fortunately, in my case, it is only used to create unique identifiers from the processed URIs.)